# Trimming HTML tags from string in PHP

Tags: php, regex, trim

Why is that `trim()` returns `i>abc</i` instead of `<i>abc</i>` when using `trim($string, "<br />")` on the string below?

```
$string = "  <br />   <br /> <i>abc</i>  <br /> <br />   </br>";
```

I wanted to remove all `<br />` tags from the beginning and end of the string considering that there might be some whitespaces in between `<br>` tags.

Any suggestions or workarounds?

Comment: Did you read the documentation for [trim](http://www.php.net)? It doesn't trim `<br />`. It trims `<`'s then `b`'s, then `r`'s, then spaces, then `/`'s and finally `>`'s.

Comment: Have a look at the function description on the [`trim` manual page](http://php.net/trim).

Comment: What about strip_tags?

Comment: `I wanted to remove all <br /> tags from the beginning and end of the string`, so you don't want to remove the `br` tags which was present at the middle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second parameter to [trim](http://php.net/trim) isn't a string as such, more a list of chars you want to strip from the start and end of the string. So, you're telling to strip all leading and trailing `<`, `>`, `\`, `b` and `r` characters.

Could try something like this regex to strip what you want from the front and end of a string...

```
//trim from start
$str=preg_replace('{^(?:<br />|</br>|\s+)+}', '', $str);
//trim from end
$str=preg_replace('{(?:<br />|</br>|\s+)+$}', '', $str);
```

Just to break down that first one...

- I've used `{}` to delimit my regex, just so I don't need to escape the matches on backslashes which I'd have to if I used the 'normal' `//` delimiter
- `^` anchors the match to the start of the string
- `(?:  )` is just a group of things we want to look for
- inside the group, we match either `<br />`, `</br>` or any whitespace sequence `\s+` - you can see each of these patterns is separated by `|` to indicate each is a possible alternative match
- the group is followed by `+` to indicate we want to find one or more matches of that group

The second one is similar, but anchored to the end of the string with `$`

Comment: This is weird, but true. They should have allowed string or array instead. Sometimes I want to trim a sequence of chars.

Comment: @Paul You could combine the both using `|` operator., and also your regex won't match `</br>` .

Comment: Didn't want to make it too hard to follow - have added in a match for </br> though, well spotted.

Comment: typo in your regex `(:?` instead of `(?:` . @op note that this regex or mine would match also the spaces which are at the beginning of `<space>foo` string. If you don't care about that. Then no prob..

Comment: Well spotted - funnily enough it still works with the typo, since it turns it into a regular group but with an optional `:` char at the start! fixed!

Answer (score 0):

The second parameter of `trim()` is a string containing all **characters** that will be trimmed. Not words or substrings, but **characters**. It means that `<` and `>` will be trimmed too, and this is what happens.

What you need to do is either `str_replace` the `<br />` out before the trim, like `str_replace('<br />', '', $string)`, or do a `strip_tags($string, '<i>')` that will delete all tags except `<i>`

Answer (score 0):

> I wanted to remove all `<br>` tags from the beginning and end of the string.

```
preg_replace('~^(?:\s|<br\h*\/>|<\/br>)+|(?:\s|<br\h*\/>|<\/br>)+$~m', '', $string);
```

`\h*` matches zero or more horizontal spaces.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/fK2mF3/1)

Comment: @Avanash Raj, if I could upvote you too, I would, since your answer is also right. Anyways thanks for the help! :)